# Imposible to find element with php simple_html_dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am trying to crawl a specific website and regardless whatever I try it is impossible to find specific element (url that links to each product in the category I am trying to crawl) . Here is what I am doing:

```
//category url
$target_url = 'https://zora.bg/tehnika/epilator';
$html = get_headers($target_url);
if($html[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'){
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($target_url);

$products=$html->find("a[class='a2.f16.l120.semi']");

foreach($products as $singleproducturl){
echo $singleproducturl;
   }    
}else echo 'url is invalid !';
```

This is 1 of the elements it needs to find:

```
<a class="a2 f16 l120 semi" href="crown/chc-6630g/24984">Машинка за подстригване Crown CHC-6630G</a>
```

but no success any way I tried.. Can you please try and tell me what I am doing wrong? 
Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: you can't just scrape it that way, its loaded via AJAX

Comment: how it can be done Ghost?

Comment: Try `a[class='.a2.f16.l120.semi']"` instead of `a[class='a2.f16.l120.semi']"`.

Comment: check out if they have an API available instead of hacking your way to get the data, just use your inspect element with the browser, the jquery code is already there

Comment: Nikhil, doesnt work, Ghost is right about ajax and I did not noticed this before Ghost's suggestion. I think it is impossible if page is loaded by ajax ..

Comment: Ghost, they don't have API neither they know I am crawling.. Is there a way to slow down scrapper until ajax is being loaded?

Comment: @thecore7 just get the endpoint address, use your browser, inspect element then review the JS codes, you'll see the address then use the following parameters, then the usual, use curl then use the dom functions you want

Comment: thank you Ghost, I will give it a try !

Comment: You're missing up your css selectors. It's either `a.a2.f16.xxx` or `a[class="a2 f12 xxx"]`